# Why does this multithreaded python program print from 0 to 99 CORRECTLY?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

This is the code.

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import *

threadLock = Lock()

def do_stuff(q):
  while True:
    threadLock.acquire()
    print q.get()
    q.task_done()
    threadLock.release()

q = Queue(maxsize=0)
num_threads = 10

for x in range(100):
  q.put(x)

for i in range(num_threads):
  worker = Thread(target=do_stuff, args=(q,))
  worker.setDaemon(False)
  worker.start()



q.join()
```

When I execute this code, I get the numbers from 0 to 99 printed perfectly sorted. When I remove the locks in do_stuff, I expect the numbers from 0 to 99 to be printed unsorted, however even with some erroneour numbers here and there, it mostly prints the range sorted again from 0 to 99. Why is that? Shouldn't it be unsorted, since I'm not synchronizing the threads in any way?

Comment: Your threads don't do nearly enough to be interrupted all that often. Your *queue* provides the numbers in sorted order, after all.

Comment: You get the number from the queue and immediately print it. There's not much time for another thread to pull his number from the queue and print it before the other thread printed its number. Might be more random if the threads are doing more work between pulling and printing the numbers.

Comment: There should be no need for the threadLock since Queue should be thread safe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your function doesn't do anything else between retrieving the next number from the queue and printing it.

Python holds a lock (the GIL) while executing each bytecode, so only *between* bytecodes can threads switch. Looking at the function (without locks) shows us that there is only *one* spot where a thread switch would give another thread the chance to grab a next number and print it before the preceding thread can print theirs:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def do_stuff(q):
...   while True:
...     print q.get()
...     q.task_done()
... 
>>> dis.dis(do_stuff)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              31 (to 34)
        >>    3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       33

  3           9 LOAD_FAST                0 (q)
             12 LOAD_ATTR                1 (get)
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             18 PRINT_ITEM          
             19 PRINT_NEWLINE       

  4          20 LOAD_FAST                0 (q)
             23 LOAD_ATTR                2 (task_done)
             26 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             29 POP_TOP             
             30 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
        >>   33 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   34 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             37 RETURN_VALUE
```

Even if the thread switched there, another thread must then complete both the `CALL_FUNCTION` *and* the `PRINT_ITEM` bytecodes before control switched back, for you to see items being printed out of order.

The thread switch would have to take place between `CALL_FUNCTION` and `PRINT_ITEM`. If you introduced more instructions there, you'd increase the chances of numbers being printed out of order.